# Loop svg path animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I've been animating some map paths using svg and have the following code.

```
var paths = document.querySelectorAll('.path');

for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {

    var length = paths[i].getTotalLength();
    // Clear any previous transition
    paths[i].style.transition = paths[i].style.WebkitTransition ='none';
    // Set up the starting positions
    paths[i].style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    paths[i].style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
    // picks up the starting position before animating
    paths[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition
    paths[i].style.transition = paths[i].style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 7s ease-in-out';
    // Go!
    paths[i].style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

}
```

I'm wanting the animation to be infinite so that it starts again once it's completed.

I have

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

within my css but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Can anybody suggest how I'd do this within the js please?

There's also a codepen here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozxyam

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your code. Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, just been working with jQuery so had it in my head! It's been edited.

Answer (score 0):

A transition is for going from one CSS state to another.

If you want a looping animation, then you should use the `animation` CSS properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation